# Why did European people settle in America and later create another nation of their own?

Tags: american-revolution, north-america

Now, in North America, mostly white people live. They are not the real natives—it's the American Indians. They are mostly from England and other powerful European nations at that time who were bent on gaining more power and wealth from colonization.

They brought black Africans to America to work as slaves, and gradually settled down themselves. But, why on earth did they go on to create a separate nation for their own? Why did they fight their own people? Why did the Americans so decidedly hate England that they even went on to make a different version of English?

---

I want a simple explanation in general terms. I only need the summary—I don't really need to know every single detail. I'm no historian, just a 13-year-old from the East who likes learning about the West.

Comment: Vtc as too broad. There appear to be several different questions here, I suggest you pick one and concentrate on that. Also read the Wikipedia entries on the causes of the [American Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Revolution#Origin).

Comment: Religious persecution mostly, to start. Read up on the Mayflower Pilgrims, the Quakers and Amish, and William Penn.

Comment: I gather you're not an English speaker...please note that "Red Indian" is a somewhat offensive way to refer to those peoples.  "American Indian" was the traditional non-offensive description, "Native American" the more common one now.

Comment: Note that the American Indians were no more "native" than the Europeans, they just immigrated earlier.  So ask why they immigrated.

Comment: @Steven Burnap: In point of fact, many if not most American Indians consider "Native American" to be somewhat offensive, and don't consider "Indian" to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Common Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Sense_%28pamphlet%29), Thomas Paine wrote, "there is something very absurd in supposing a continent to be perpetually governed by an island."

The United States was a country of continental size, far away from England. As such, the people that controlled it naturally wanted to have their own destinies. After a few generations, the "colonists" lost some of their feelings for the "mother" country (which many had never visited), and developed feelings for each other, that is, their peers.

Collectively, the "colonists" woke up one day, looked at each other, thought, and said something like, "If we throw out the mother country, we can have this vast continent all to ourselves."

I call it the "130 year itch" (for British colonies). Australia was settled in 1770 and became independent in 1900. Canada became independent in 1871; the transfer from French to British holdings began with a war in 1741. America's 1776 Declaration of Independence is 130 years after 1646; a good "time-weighted" average of American settlement.

A similar thing happened to the Spanish colonies in South America, but not on the 130 year timetable.

Comment: Tom Au, I respect you so much for being able to summarize an entire college course in a few short paragraphs.

Comment: Note that [England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England) is roughly the same area as the US state of North Carolina. The US colonies at this time covered about 5.5x more land area than England and had nearly half its population (although 5% of it was enslaved).

Comment: I hope the OP at least gets an A for this answer, now that you did her assignment. >.<

Comment: @Marakai This is no assignment, but simply a little question that suddenly popped up into my mind yesterday.